# highchart donut - click on slice opens page by searching from userService

Tags: javascript, angular, donut-chart

I have a donut pie chart. on click of legend item it navigates to particular page which it retrieves from userSevice like given below -

[pic of user service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAok2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAok2.png)

legendItemClick:

```
function(e) { debugger;
    this.userService.search(e.target.id);
    return false;
}.bind(this)
```

i am looking for same functionality when i click on the pie slices of the chart it should navigate to particular related page. i tried this below but was not successful -

```
point: {
    events: {   
        click: function(e){
            this.userService.search(e.target.id);
            return false;
        }.bind(this)
    }
}
```

any help where Iam going wrong ?

userService -

```
  search(id: any) {
        let headers = new Headers();


        let data = { "jql": id };
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let http: Http
       var method = method || "post";
        var params;
        var path ;       
        path = ' http://imptdg/IMR/Ticket/DashBoard';
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", method);
                form.setAttribute("action", path);          
                        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", 'jql');
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", id);
                        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                document.body.appendChild(form); debugger;
                form.submit();



    }


defaults() {
    this.options = {

        title: { text: ' ' },
        colors: ['rgba(79, 162, 189, 1)', 'rgba(84, 135, 201, 1)', 'rgba(143, 185, 91, 1)', 'rgba(90, 183, 130, 1)', 'rgba(71, 195, 185, 1)', 'rgba(190, 120, 203, 1)', 'rgba(228, 211, 84, 1)', 'rgba(43, 144, 143, 1)', 'rgba(145, 232, 225, 1)'],
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            animation: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 300
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        labelFormatter: function () {
                            return '<div style="width:180px"><span class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family:Helvetica ">' + this.name +
                                '</span><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500" >' + this.value +
                                '</span></div> ';
                        }
                    },
                    pie: {
                        size: 50,
                        innerSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '40%',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                slicedOffset: 0,                    
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                showInLegend: true,                                   
                 point: {
                    events: {   
                        click:function(e){ 
                            this.userService.search(e.target.id); // this part not working
                            return false;
                        }.bind(this), 

                        legendItemClick: function (e) { 

                            this.userService.search(e.target.id);
                            return false;
                        }.bind(this),

                    }

                    },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        halo: {
                            size: 0
                        },
                        enabled : true
                    }
                }
            },

            series: {
                animation: false,

                }

                },




        },

        legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            layout: 'vertical',
            symbolHeight: 12,
            itemMarginBottom: 1,
            symbolWidth: 25,
            symbolRadius: 1,
            labelFormatter: function () {
                return '<div style="width:180px;"><div class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 3px;padding-top:3px;  width: 130px; font-family:Helvetica; white-space: normal; word-break:break-word ">' + this.name 

            },


            },
        },

        series: [{
            data: this.donutchartData,
            allowPointSelect: true
        }]
    };

}
```

}

Comment: What does your `userService.search` method look like?

Comment: @LLai taken a screenshot of user service look while i was trying to debug it and understand. i have updated the question with pic.

Comment: Can you add your UserService code as text instead of a pic. It will help users debug your code easier. I am unsure what you are trying to do. You said you are trying to navigate to a related page. Why not use angular's built in router?

Comment: @LLai - it is not fetching id , as in the pic you can see its blank. I am not able to get the id of the slice clikced!!

Comment: @LLai - updated question

Comment: @LLai - its an existing functionality of application, cannot chnage it now.

Comment: Where do you assign the ids? Within the series data?

Comment: @LLai - updated in question

Comment: I'm still failing to see where the id gets assigned. Is it within `this.donutchartData`? something like `[{name: 'Category 1', id: 1, y: 20}, ...]`

Comment: @LLai yes its coming from this.donutchartdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working now, i have gone through the api documentation of highchart donut - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.events.click. now it is navigating and taing me to proper page that i was looking for.

```
point: {
                            events: {   
                                click:function(e){ 

                                    this.userService.search(e.point.id);

                                }.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your series data is something like `[{name: 'Category 1', id: 1, y: 20}, ...]` you need to fetch the id from the point clicked

```
defaults() {
    let self = this; // store this in self so you can use component this and highcharts point event this
    this.options = {
        // other options
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                point: {
                    function(e){ 
                        let id = this.id; // get id from series data
                        self.userService.search(id);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```